# .txt altered after save leads to CSV reader seeing too many fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a `JupyterLab` on `AWS SageMaker`. Kernel: `conda_amazonei_mxnet_p27`

The number of fields found: `saw 9` increments by 1, each run.

**Error:** `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 50, saw 9`

---

#### Code:

Invocation (Error doesn't appear when running all cells before this but does when this is ran):

```py
train = open('train_textcorrupted.csv', 'a')
val = open('val.csv', 'a')
classes = open('classes.txt', 'a')
uni_label = 'Organisation\tUniversity'
n_pad = 4
for i in range(len(unis)-n_pad):
    record = ' '.join(unis[i:(i+n_pad)])
    full_record = f'{uni_label}\t{record}\n'
    if random.random() > 0.9:
        val.write(full_record)
    else:
        train.write(full_record) 

classes.write(uni_label)
classes.close() 
val.close()
train.close()
```

#### Traceback:

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-89b1728bd5a6> in <module>
      7       --gpus 1
      8     """.split()
----> 9 run_training(args)
<ipython-input-5-091daf2638a1> in run_training(input)
     55     csv_logger = pl.loggers.CSVLogger(save_dir=f'{args.modeldir}/csv_logs')
     56     loggers = [logger, csv_logger]
---> 57     dm = OntologyTaggerDataModule.from_argparse_args(args)
     58     if args.model_uri:
     59         local_model_uri = os.environ.get('SM_CHANNEL_MODEL', '.')
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/datamodule.py in from_argparse_args(cls, args, **kwargs)
    324         datamodule_kwargs.update(**kwargs)
    325 
--> 326         return cls(**datamodule_kwargs)
    327 
    328     @classmethod
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/datamodule.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
     47 
     48         # Get instance of LightningDataModule by mocking its __init__ via __call__
---> 49         obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
     50 
     51         return obj
<ipython-input-3-66ee2be72e78> in __init__(self, traindir, train_file, validate_file, model_name, labels, batch_size)
     30         print('tokenizer', tokenizer)
     31         print('labels_file', labels_file)
---> 32         label_mapper = LabelMapper(labels_file)
     33         self.batch_size = batch_size
     34         self.num_classes = label_mapper.num_classes
<ipython-input-3-66ee2be72e78> in __init__(self, classes_file)
    102 
    103     def __init__(self, classes_file):
--> 104         self._raw_labels = pd.read_csv(classes_file, header=None, sep='\t')
    105 
    106         self._map = []
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    686     )
    687 
--> 688     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    689 
    690 
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    458 
    459     try:
--> 460         data = parser.read(nrows)
    461     finally:
    462         parser.close()
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1196     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1197         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1198         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1199 
   1200         # May alter columns / col_dict
~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_latest_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2155     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2156         try:
-> 2157             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2158         except StopIteration:
   2159             if self._first_chunk:
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 50, saw 9
```

---

`classes.txt` (tab-separated) Before runtime

```
Activity    Event
Actor   Person
Agent   Person
Album   Product
Animal  Object
ArchitecturalStructure  Location
Artist  Person
Athlete Person
AutomobileEngine    Product
Award   Object
Biomolecule Object
Bird    Object
BodyOfWater Location
Building    Location
ChemicalSubstance   Object
Company Organisation
Competition Event
Device  Product
Disease Object
District    Location
Eukaryote   Object
Event   Event
Film    Object
Food    Object
Language    Object
Location    Location
MeanOfTransportation    Product
MotorsportSeason    Event
Municipality    Location
MusicalWork Product
Organisation    Organisation
Painter Person
PeriodicalLiterature    Product
Person  Person
PersonFunction  Person
Plant   Object
Poet    Person
Politician  Person
River   Location
School  Organisation
Settlement  Location
Software    Product
Song    Product
Species Object
SportsSeason    Event
Station Location
Town    Location
Village Location
Writer  Person
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
Organisation    University
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve] — without that, we can only guess.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. However, (1) **please reduce the code to its essential core** — most of what you’ve posted is irrelevant for the issue you’re seeing. (2) you also need to provide the input data (again: reduced as much as possible while still reproducing the issue).

Comment: Sure, Ty for help. Downloading datasets so as I can add more details to post @KonradRudolph

Comment: I've added all of them now @KonradRudolph

Comment: Major update at top of post @KonradRudolph

Comment: Please don’t answer your own question *inside the question* — instead, put it into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Found:

So no fault of my own, I keep ensuring these fields are on their own lines in `classes.txt` and `Ctrl+S`. Then when I reopen the file, **after runtime**, it'll have fields be on the same line again.

[image]

To fix this, on line `classes.write(uni_label)`.

I replaced it with `classes.write('\n'+uni_label)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks very much for your advice and support. Appreciated.